# How to check screen on or off event of android only user behavior

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-wake-lock, android-screen

I want to show some screen on the lock screen when the screen is turned on. So I wrote the following code.

```
public class BroadcastReceiverScreen extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null && 
       Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(intent.getAction())) {

    } else if (intent.getAction() != null && 
      Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    }
}
```

However, when the user does not turn on the screen with the power button, the **alarm clock, message, etc are automatically displayed** when the screen is turned on.

**I want to make it work only when the user turns on the screen.**

For example, when the phone rings, you can detect and avoid the following code.

```
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                isPhoneIdle = true;
                //Log.e("PhoneCallState", "STATE_IDLE");
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isPhoneIdle = false;
                //Log.e("PhoneCallState", "STATE_RINGING : Incoming number " 
               + incomingNumber);
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //Log.e("PhoneCallState", "STATE_OFFHOOK");
                isPhoneIdle = false;
            }
        }
    };
```

**In conclusion, can the user detect it only when the screen is turned on?
Not automatically turned on screen.**

Thank you.